# How to identify where to edit content in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have inherited a 7 drupal site but I'm not sure where in the dashboard to edit text. The site has 4 `content types` but when i click edit beside the content I get details for `title`,`body`(which is empty) `url aliases` and other metadata but no text to edit.

I have views UI enabled but they relate to the WebForm content type which I can edit

Comment: The page content may be in a block or view. Have a look at the class names in the source html to get a clue where you can change the content.

Comment: Yes, check the page source and specially CSS classes added to html <body> element - they my hide valuable information.

Answer (score 2):

You have to login in to admin and goes to `/admin/content` URL. You get the list of all content also have to filter of `type`, you can select the content type which you want to edit. If you do not find as i have mention please attach a screenshot what you get.

Comment: This is not an answer. Maybe his output is coming from a block or view. Looking at the list of nodes does not **identify where to edit content**.

Answer (score 0):

I have access to the list on `/admin/content` but when I clicked the edit button on the right beside the content i wish to edit I get `[Title, Menu Settings, Revision information, Comments settings, URL Path Settings, Authoring Information, Publishing Options]` but no actual content to edit on the Edit tab

The author details is different so that got me thinking about permissions, I checked permissions and the administrator account didn't have permission to `edit any content` for each of the `content types`.

Comment: so you have to give the permission to edit the content

Comment: yes but only after modifying the permissions for the adminstrators group. The content was originally created under a different administrator account

Comment: so what is the issue, if have same group then you can also edit it.

Comment: Before the permissions to edit other content was not enabled for the admin group so only an author would be able to edit their content. As my account didn't author any content it could not edit any

Comment: Yes that's correct, If you want to edit you have to give the permission else it will work as it is working.

Comment: Why have you added this as an answer? edit your original question to add more details.